# If $A=XX^*$ then all eigenvalues of $A^{(-1)}$ are positive?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A\in M_n $.

Suppose $A=XX^*$ and $A$ be positive semidefinite and $X$ is non- zero vector.

Why are, all eigenvalues of $A^{(-1)}$ positive?

(Note:   $A^{(−1)} = [a^{−1}_{i j} ]$ and ${a_{ij}} \ne 0$ for all $i$ and $j$)

Comment: Do you count $0$ as positive? In this situation, $A^{(-1)}$ has rank $1$, so for $n > 1$, it has an $(n-1)$-fold eigenvalue $0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer yes, but if $A=XX^*$ then $A$ has rank 1, why does $A^{(-1)}$ rank 1?

Comment: Because $A^{(-1)} = X^{(-1)}\cdot (X^{(-1)})^{\ast}$.

Comment: Does $A^{(-1)}$ mean element wise inverse? If yes, then it is not necessarily a PSD matrix.

Try to paste the following code in MATLAB and taste it.

X = rand(4,2); Y = X*X'; Yinv = Y.^(-1); [v,e] = eig(Yinv);